# Making a div only appear on mouseover

Tags: css

I'm working on a fairly simple site but one of the things I do want is a div which only appears on mouseover. I have used the following method:

```
.mydiv {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150px;
    color: #ffff00;
    position: absolute;
    width: 680px;
    height: 180px;
    z-index: 15;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -90px 0 0 -340px;
    background: black;
    display: none;
}

.mydiv:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: if your div is display:none, the event hover not firing

Comment: If your div is `display: none`, there's nothing to hover over.

Comment: You cant hover over a hidden div, you'll have to hover over something else to show the div.

Answer (score 1):

`display:none;` keeps your element from being in the layout.  Put something there to hover over that will take its place while it's hidden (or just use `visibility:hidden;` instead).

You can place the div inside of a container div that will produce the hover function like this:

```
.container:hover > .mydiv {
    display: block;
}
```

Expanding on the `visibility:hidden;` - doing this will still take up space but since it's position is absolute you don't have to worry about the other elements moving because of it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hover over an invisible element. It's not there to receive hover events, and it will take up literally no space in your document.

If you want this to work, you need to use a parent `<div>` which preserves the space, and use `parent_div:hover child_div { display:block }` to show the hidden div.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `display: none`, the div does not display on the page at all.  Therefore, you can't hover on it to trigger the `:hover` css.

Try using `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`.  This way, the div remains on the page as an invisible element, and when you hover over its location on the page, it will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it really simple, by setting the opacity to 0 when you want it to be invisible, and then on hover, increasing it to 1.

```
.mydiv {
    /* your code */
    opacity: 0;
}
.mydiv:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

If you want it to be smooth, you can add a transition:

```
.mydiv {
    /* your code */
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.mydiv:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `div` is not visible, then it won't receive the event. How can it? If it does have the `display: none` property, where would the user hover on for it to turn visible? Yuo need an event target.

One thing you can do is have a target element that you do hover on, and a child `div` that appears on hover.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/v37Tt/

HTML

```
<div id="master">
    hover for surprise!
    <div id="popup">
        Happy surprise party!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#master {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: pink;
    width: 150px;
}

#popup {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    background: yellow;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

#master:hover #popup {
    display: block;
}
```

What's important here is that the `#master` `div` gets hovered, and the rule for a `#popup` child of a hover'ed `#master` is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two Divs.  One to respond to the hover event and your original div.

I am going to use jquery for the example.

```
        <div id="DivToRespondToMouseHover">
        Something to be hoverable.
        </div>
        <div class="mydiv">
         I am hidden until someone hovers over "DivToRespondeToMouseHover"
        </div>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
          //When the document loads correct. Attach a hover event handler to 
          $("#DivToResponToMouseHover").hover(function(){
            $(".mydiv").show(); //Use the standard jQuery show
          });
        });
        </script>
```

Add your styles and stuff as normal.
Why does this happen:
But something that is not shown can not respond to user events on its own.  Because the element is not really there nothing is to hovered over. Until it becomes visible it may not fire the event.

Any use Jquery it is really great for this stuff (if you are not already using it).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the div visible to be able to fire the mouseover/hover events in the first place.  Consider using JavaScript (jQuery can do this nicely) to hide the contained elements of an outer div with a fixed size on mouseover.

```
$('#parentDiv').hover(function(){
    $('#childDiv').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes ,You are near about to css.You have to find out  at first the selector that means in which selector I have to use.Ok that means If I hover on body tag then all content will show.
Below the code use and try to understand!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Margin Auto</title>
    <style>

.mydiv {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:30px;
        color: #ffff00;
        position:absolute;
        width:680px;
        height:180px;
        z-index:15;
        margin:0px auto;
        background:#FF0000;
        display:none;
    }
    #hoverme:hover .mydiv {
        display:block;
    }


    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="hoverme">
<p>Hover me</p>
<div class="mydiv">

   Content goes here!

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```